# Inflating panel.java by default in android

Tags: android, panel

I'm using [an android panel widget](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/source/browse/trunk/android-misc-widgets/src/org/miscwidgets/widget/Panel.java?r=9) in my application to create a sliding panel effect from the top of my app (similar to the notification panel).  When clicked the panel opens to fill about 30% of the screen.  By default the panel is closed and has a handle to "show".  I'm trying to modify it to be in the shown state by default but am unsure how to do it.  I assume that I'll have to modify the Panel.java file but I suppose it might also be done in my layout file.. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're defining your own class which extends Panel...in your onCreate() override, you could try calling `setOpen(true, false);` ?

**EDIT** As you're not extending it yourself, you could simply call the setOpen() method as soon as your activity is created instead. Example...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected Panel topPanel = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        topPanel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.top_panel);
        topPanel.setOpen(true, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way I'm calling it for now is in the main.xml layout file: as follows:  <com.testapp.show15.Panel android:id="@+id/top_panel" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

Comment: @Vince W: Happy to help - have fun. :-)